# Run a macro when I click a powerpoint shape in edit mode

Tags: vba, powerpoint, mouseclick-event

I want to be able to change some values of a certain shape when I click on it. But I want to make it when powerpoint is in edit mode (I don't know if it is said like that), not in slide show mode. I have been looking on Internet and I only found a way to make it on slide show mode, so when the presentation is running.

Here is the code that I found

```
Private Sub createSwipeNext(color)
    Dim swipArrow As Shape
    Dim subName As String
    subName = "Identify"
    Set cSlide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
    'ActiveWindow.Selection.Unselect
    Set swipArrow = cSlide.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRightArrow, ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.width + 10, ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.height / 2, 40, 30)
    If color = "green" Then
        swipArrow.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
    Else
        swipArrow.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
    End If
    swipArrow.name = "Dink swipe arrow"

    'swipArrow.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Run = subName
    With swipArrow.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick) ' or ppMouseOver if you prefer
         .Run = subName
         .Action = ppActionRunMacro
      End With
 End Sub
```

With this code is possible to click to the shape on slide Show mode and run Identify() method. I want to make the same but in edit mode, so when the presentation is not running. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Possible but definitely not easy. You would need to write a class module to detect the selection event.

The code posted doesn't make a lot of sense. Maybe start again and just say **what** you want to happen when the shape is clciked (in show mode)

Comment: Hiya John.   The posted code seems to set the shape up so that it'll run the subroutine found in the variable Subname when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to do so i just did it my self right now all you need is download this file
http://www.officeoneonline.com/eventgen/EventGen20.zip
install it
create a class module
paste this code
Option Explicit

```
Public WithEvents PPTEvent As Application



Private Sub Class_Initialize()
End Sub


Private Sub PPTEvent_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
If Sel.Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
    If Sel.ShapeRange.HasTextFrame Then
        If Sel.ShapeRange.TextFrame.HasText Then
           If Trim(Sel.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Text) = "Text inside your shape" Then
              Sel.Unselect
              yoursub
           End If
       End If
     End If

   End If
```

End Sub

insert a new module
paste this code

Dim cPPTObject As New Class1

Dim TrapFlag As Boolean

```
 Sub TrapEvents()
      If TrapFlag = True Then
         MsgBox "Already Working"
         Exit Sub
      End If
    Set cPPTObject.PPTEvent = Application
    TrapFlag = True
 End Sub




 Sub ReleaseTrap()
      If TrapFlag = True Then
         Set cPPTObject.PPTEvent = Nothing
         Set cPPTObject = Nothing
         TrapFlag = False
      End If
 End Sub

 Sub yoursub()
         MsgBox "Your Sub is working"
 End Sub
```

Now run TrapEvents and whenver you will click shape with that text in it your sub will run
Credits to the person who wrote this http://www.officeoneonline.com/eventgen/eventgen.html